# What is the difference between secondary/grammar/primary/grade/etc. school?

Tags: word-difference, transatlantic-differences

There are some minor differences between primary, grade and elementary school, but let's forget them. The same goes for secondary, grammar and middle school.

The question is about different school names for the same grades and which one is preferred in American or British English.

I'm not sure if `grammar school` term exists at all, but that's what I got from a translator.

Comment: I'm deleting the question as I don't know what else I can do to improve it.

Comment: I can't delete it as others have invested time and effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Primary school` and `elementary school` are the **same**. The only difference is that elementary school is the preferred term in American and Canadian English.

Education in United States consists of three stages:

1. elementary school
2. middle school
3. high school

Middle schools usually offer classes for students in sixth, seventh and eighth grades (some of them offer classes for ninth grade too) and prepares students for high school.

Education in United Kingdom consists of two phases:

1. primary school
2. secondary school

Secondary schools refer to high schools and prep schools.

Comment: Worth noting that some school districts might vary from this a little bit. I know one school district whose elementary school was K-3, middle school was Grades 4-6, with a Junior High School for grades 7 and 8. But I've upvoted your summary, which covers the general case pretty well.

Comment: @J.R. Yes. Thanks for adding useful information to this post.

Answer (score 0):

In Britain.

Ages 4-11 are Primary school
Ages 11-18 is Secondary School (with education compulsory to age 16)

In British English "Primary" is preferred to "Elementary".  Middle Schools have been phased out in most places, but would have covered ages 9-14. "Secondary" is prefered to "High" school.

Grammar Schools are secondary schools that are selective. They take the top attaining 25% of students.  In most areas, state grammar schools have been phased out.  Comprehensive schools are secondary schools that do not select on ability.

Private and Independent schools are schools that are not run by the state. Public schools are a type of traditional Independent school, this differs from American use where "Public School" means the same as "State School". The term "public school" comes from a time when the Government didn't have schools. Either you had a private education at home with a parent or tutor, or a public education at a school.

So the main differences are:

- "Primary" not "Elementary",
- "Secondary" not "Middle" or "High",
- "State" not "Public".

Comment: It is no longer true that all grammar schools are State schools in England: when, for reasons too complicated to go into here, the State decided that grammar schools were a bad idea, some of those schools, such as Manchester Grammar School, for example, became independent of the State.